# Maquetar un link dentro de un mailing?

Tags: html, email

Tengo un mailing que envío a mis usuarios en el cual requiero mandarle este enlace:

> Si no funciona el link, copia y pega este enlace en tu navegador:
>   https://dominio/validating-email/eyJpdiI6Ik92dDVFdFdROVwvK0MwOWIrRUllcDRRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlNTdU1BNUljSEtxcjYyUTY4N1I5bmo3UzhzUjd4UnFmRFNCaVJTalNvd2wxc3FiSTAiLCJtYWMiOiJmMjMzZjJjZjJmNTlmYTdiODdjNTZjNjZhYTgwZjExYmQ0NDFlYzU2Yzk5NDQwY2Y1NDY1M2E5NzE1MThkMzQ5In0=

El problema es que se des-maqueta todo el contenido.

Este es el código:

```css
a {
    width: 600px; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word; 
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-word; 
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<a 
    href="https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating-email/{{$data->token}}">
         https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating-email/{{$data->token}}
    </a>
```

Este es el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿podrías usar la ruta `validating_email` en vez de `validating-email`? Parece que se corta por el guión

Comment: ya lo hice pero sigue estando en una sola linea

Comment: Pues entonces no entiendo que es lo que quieres, deberías explicar a que te refieres con *des-maqueta* . Pon imagen de como aparece y otra de como desearías que quede.

Answer (score 1):

Para prevenir el salto de línea que está haciendo "-", puedes usar el guión `&#8209;` que previene este salto de línea:

```
<a 
    href="https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating-email/{{$data->token}}">
    https://{{ $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] }}/validating&#8209;email/{{$data->token}}
</a>
```

Comment: Hola Si funciona lo que me dijiste, pero sigue estando en una sola linea lo cual causa que se desmaquete el mailing